# UpperCase all Xml element values with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XDocument with a number of elements/child elements etc and I'd like to make the Value of each element UpperCase.

```
doc.Descendants().ToList().ForEach(f => f.Value = f.Value.ToUpper());
```

doesn't work because it concatenates ALL the values (as upper) into the parent element.

Comment: As a suggestion, when you want to ask a question about C#, ALWAYS flag it as C#. NOT C#-2.0, C#-4.0... C#! You can add other tags with the exact version, if your question is version dependant, but ALWAYS put the C# tag. No one responded to your question not because it was difficult, but because many persons "filter" the questions they see with the most common tags (C#, .NET, LINQ). If you move the mouse on the tags your question now has, you'll see C# 23.7K followers, LINQ 3.2k followers and your tags 206 and 3 followers. BIG difference :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ expressions shouldn't normally modify the value of the source. They should only return new values (think them as a filter... You put something in, something different comes out)

```
foreach (var desc in doc.Descendants()) {
    var nodes = desc.Nodes().Where(p => p.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text);

    foreach (XText node in nodes) {
        node.Value = node.Value.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way - not sure its the best but it works.

```
private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(txtXml.Text);
        ProcessElement(doc.Elements().First());
        txtXml.Text = doc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
    }

    private void ProcessElement(XElement element)
    {
        if (element.HasElements)
            element.Elements().ToList().ForEach(e => ProcessElement(e));
        else
            element.Value = element.Value.ToUpper();
    }
```